# how to uninstall homebrew using an arm based Mac?

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I installed homebrew today. And I did something wrong so that my homebrew can't work now. Since I use an arm based mac, I am hard to find solution to uninstall my homebrew which installed in `/opt/homebrew/.`

Answer (score 8):

To uninstall Homebrew, run the uninstall script from the Homebrew/install repository.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

Download the uninstall script and run `/bin/bash uninstall.sh --help` to view more uninstall options.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your homebrew path is correct and then run the script:

```
echo $HOMEBREW_PREFIX #=> /opt/homebrew
```

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

See: https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew

Comment: `echo $HOMEBREW_PREFIX` returned the right value but I still got an error: `Failed to locate Homebrew!`. Fixed it by adding `arch -arm64` in front of the install command.