# how to solve this python installation error with asdf?

Tags: python, linux, asdf, arch, asdf-vm

I'm trying to install python with asdf, so I've tried everything and it's not working

```
[lucaslinux@lucasPC ~]$ asdf install python latest
python-build 3.11.2 /home/lucaslinux/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.2
Downloading Python-3.11.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.2/Python-3.11.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.2...

BUILD FAILED (Arch Linux using python-build 2.3.13-1-g86a4423b)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20230215220228.5116
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20230215220228.5116.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "linux"
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/python-build.20230215220228.5116/Python-3.11.2':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I tried to install python through asdf, I searched about it and found nothing

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the very same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 installing the system dependencies as explained [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment) .

Answer (score 0):

install these packages in your arch, I don't know the specific names in the arch but a little google search gives it.
[image]

Comment: FONT: https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-python/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate from a MacOS with an Intel CPU? Because the problem could be Homebrew.

> The solution is to completely remove Homebrew ([how to uninstall homebrew using an arm based Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447875/how-to-uninstall-homebrew-using-an-arm-based-mac)) and install it from scratch. It should install arm64/M1 version. Then install `asdf` and you can install Python for M1. — [source](https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-python/issues/118#issuecomment-1007060004).